# How to prove the existence of a prime number with elementary method?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose $A>5$ is an integer and there exists a prime number $p$ such that $A-2\leq p^2<A$.

Show that there exists at least one prime number $q$ such that $p<q<A$.

This seems to be intuitive to me since $A$ and $p$ has large gap. How can we prove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using one version of [Bertrand's Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate), if $q$ is the next prime after $p$ then
$$p<q<2p\le p^2<A\ .$$